Naturality for the Homotopy Fiber Sequence of Mapping Spaces
For a cartesian fibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ of $\infty$-categories (quasicategories) and objects $x,y$ of $\mathcal{E}$, the induced map $\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py)$ of mapping spaces is a Kan fibration. For a morphism $\varphi\colon px\rightarrow py$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we may pick a cartesian lift $\overline{\varphi}\colon x^{\prime}\rightarrow y$ in $\mathcal{E}$, necessarily $px=px^{\prime}$. Then, there is a homotopy fiber sequence
$$\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime})\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py).$$
Here, $\mathcal{E}_{px}$ is the fiber of $\mathcal{E}$ over $px$. The first horizontal map is obtained from the inclusion $\mathcal{E}_{px}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{E}$ and post-composition with $\overline{\varphi}$. The latter is only defined up to homotopy, so the statement is supposed to mean that a) it is possible to choose a representative of this homotopy class s.t. the composite in the previous diagram is the constant map with value $\varphi$ and b) the map induced by the left horizontal map into the fiber of the right horizontal map is a homotopy-equivalence.
Now, suppose $p\colon\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and $p^{\prime}\colon\mathcal{E}^{\prime}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^{\prime}$ are cartesian fibrations and $f\colon\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}^{\prime}$ is a morphism of cartesian fibrations, i.e. $p^{\prime}f=p$ and $f$ preserves cartesian edges. I want to show that if $f$ induces a (Joyal) equivalence $\mathcal{E}_z\rightarrow\mathcal{E^{\prime}}_z$ on fibers for all objects $z$ of $\mathcal{C}$, then it is a (Joyal) equivalence. Essential surjectivity is clear. Now, to show $f$ is fully faithful, suppose $x,y$ are objects of $\mathcal{E}$. There is a "diagram of homotopy fiber sequences"
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime}) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py)\\
@VVV @VVV @|\\
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}^{\prime}_{px}}(fx,fx^{\prime}) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}^{\prime}}(fx,fy) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py).
\end{CD}
$$
A morphism of Kan fibrations over a fixed base is a homotopy equivalence if and only if it induces a homotopy equivalence on each fiber. However, the left square above features homotopy fibers instead of strict fibers and it does not strictly commute, only up to homotopy. To deduce that the induced map on strict fibers is a homotopy equivalence, I would like to factor the left square into a homotopy-commutative square with the strict fibers on the RHS. The square obviously exists, however it is not at all clear to me why it should still commute up to homotopy.
I noticed that $p$ and $p^{\prime}$ being inner fibrations allows me to choose composition laws in $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E}^{\prime}$ that project to the same composition law in $\mathcal{C}$. I've tried playing around with this and the homotopy lifting property, yet have not managed to obtain the desired homotopy. So, how do I fix this argument?

We can replace $f$ by a Joyal fibration in the Joyal model structure on $\mathrm{sSet}_{/\mathcal{C}}$, because we only care to show that the middle vertical map in the diagram of homotopy fiber sequences is an equivalence. At this point, we have a commutative square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}@>{\mathrm{restriction}}>> \mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}\\
@V{f}VV @VV{f}V\\
\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2} @>{\mathrm{restriction}}>>\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1}
\end{CD}
$$
in which the vertical maps are fibrations (because $f$ was assumed to be one) and the horizontal maps are trivial fibrations. This implies that the induced map $\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}\to\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2}\times_{\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1}}\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}$ is a trivial fibration. If we choose a section $\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1}\to\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2}$ of the restriction map in the other direction (we will later make an explicit choice here), then we use the composite $\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}\xrightarrow{f}\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1}\to\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2}$ and the identity map on $\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}$ to get an induced map $\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}\to\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2}\times_{\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1}}\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}\to\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}$, where the last map is a section of the fibration in the other direction. This composite $\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}\to\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}$ is a section of the trivial fibration in the other direction, and by construction the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1} @>>>\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}\\
@V{f}VV @VV{f}V\\
\mathcal{E'}^{\Lambda^2_1} @>>>\mathcal{E'}^{\Delta^2}
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. If we now choose a map $\varphi\in\mathrm{map}_\mathcal{C}(p'x,p'y)$ and a $p$-cartesian lift $\overline{\varphi}\colon x'\to y$ of it, we can form the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime}) @>{\overline{\varphi}\circ-}>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py)\\
@VVV @VVV @|\\
\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}^{\prime}_{px}}(fx,fx^{\prime}) @>{f\overline{\varphi}\circ-}>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}^{\prime}}(fx,fy) @>>> \mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(p'x,p'y).
\end{CD}
$$
of homotopy fiber squares, which is homotopy commutative. However, if we pick a composition law for $\mathcal{E}'$ for which the bottom composite is strictly equal to the constant map on $\varphi$, then we can by the above select a composition law for $\mathcal{E}$ for which the diagram of homotopy fiber squares commutes strictly. In particular, the top row is also strictly equal to the constant map on $\varphi$, and now the result follows from the already known statement that equivalences of Kan complexes can be detected on homotopy fibers.

Thanks for your answer! This clarifies how to upgrade to a commutative square, but the initial reduction step is not quite clear to me. I'm probably misunderstanding what "fibrant replacement" you mean, but $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E}^{\prime}$ are already fibrant in $\mathbf{sSet}_{/\mathcal{C}}$ (since categorical fibrations are isofibrations). It seems like we might want to factor $f$ into a Joyal equivalence followed by an isofibration, but then it is not clear to me why restricting attention to the latter doesn't pose a less of generality.

Also, I'm now realizing my understanding of the homotopy fiber sequence is still shaky. Is it the case that $\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{E}{px}}(x,x^{\prime})\rightarrow\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{C}}(px,py)$ is a homotopy fiber sequence for any choice of composition law that makes the composite constant with value $\varphi$? I know there is such a choice, but it's not clear to me if they're all equivalent (there can be "monodromy" that I'm not sure how to make precise). Sorry for all the follow-up questions.

@Thorgott With ''fibrant replacement'' I meant replacing $f$ itself with a fibration in the Joyal model structure. This is useful, because it implies that the vertical morphisms in the first square I drew are fibrations, so the induced map towards the pullback is a trivial fibration, which hence has a section. In other words, assuming $f$ to be an equivalence allows us to use a composition law for $\mathcal{E}'$ to design one for $\mathcal{E}$ that strictly ''lies above'' it, so this strictifies your homotopy commutative square in the original question.

As for your other question: the slogan is that the space of sections of a trivial fibration is contractible. Applying this to $\mathcal{E}^{\Delta^2}\to\mathcal{E}^{\Lambda^2_1}$, we get that all composition laws are ''canonically'' equivalent to each other (with ''canonical'' here being in a homotopical sense). So yes, if you pick any composition law that makes the composite constant with value $\varphi$, then you get a homotopy fiber sequence, because the first map in your sequence is homotopy equivalent to the one for which you already knew it was part of a homotopy fiber sequence.

If you don't object to leaving the point-set world, it may be easier to look at it from the perspective of the $\infty$-category of spaces. (Accepting that such a thing exists and has the expected properties). Then the space of composition laws is the space of inverses to a certain equivalence, and is hence contractible. Moreover, (homotopy) fiber sequences are invariant under homotopy, so we don't need to worry about selecting correct representatives, nor about the composite map actually being strictly constant on $\varphi$ (instead of just being homotopic to the constant map on $\varphi$).

And, the composite being homotopic to the constant map on $\varphi$ holds for any choice of composition law.
Our point-set constructions are trying to make sure these homotopy invariance properties hold as best as we can make them in a point-set world. In practise, that means that these will hold when everything in sight is fibrant-cofibrant, and that we in general can replace everything by fibrations up to homotopy.

Thanks for your comments. I agree replacing $f$ with a fibration is useful, but it is not clear to me why it's possible. I can factor $f$ as $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}^{\prime}$, an equivalence followed by a fibration. It suffices to show $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}^{\prime}$ is an equivalence and this map is again a fiber-wise equivalence. However, it is not clear to me why the image of $\overline{\varphi}$ in $\mathcal{F}$ is a cartesian edge for $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$. And without that, there is no homotopy fiber sequence.

As for the second question, I agree with the perspective. It is also clear to me that the homotopy class $\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{E}{px}}(x,x^{\prime})\rightarrow\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)$ is uniquely determined, but if I pick to representatives that map constantly to $\varphi$, the resulting maps of $\mathrm{map}{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime})$ into the fiber over $\varphi$ may not necessarily be homotopic anymore. Morally, they should differ by a monodromy action, so one is an equivalence iff the other is, but I don't know how to make that precise in this setting.

Here is another approach to obtaining a natural homotopy fiber sequence. The precise statement obtained from the usual proof can be presented as:
Let $p\colon\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ be an inner fibration between $\infty$-categories. For objects $x,y$ of $\mathcal{E}$, a morphism $\varphi\colon px\rightarrow py$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and a $p$-cartesian lift $\overline{\varphi}\colon x^{\prime}\rightarrow y$ of $\varphi$, there is
a) a homotopy fiber sequence $X\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{C}}(px,py)$ (in which the latter map is a Kan fibration) and
b) a homotopy equivalence $X\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime})$,
such that
c) the composite $\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}_{px}}(x,x^{\prime})\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}X\rightarrow\mathrm{map}_{\mathcal{E}}(x,y)$ obtained by inverting the map in b) provides a model for $\overline{\varphi}_{\ast}$.
The space $X$ can be taken to be the fiber of the induced map $\mathcal{E}^{/\overline{\varphi}}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^{/\varphi}$ between the fat slices over the point $\Delta^0\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^{/\varphi}$, which is classified by the $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ obtained by gluing two copies of $s_0\varphi$. The issue in the OP is that it is not necessarily possible to choose homotopy inverses as in c) naturally. The upshot now is that the maps involved in a) and b) are natural. This suffices to carry out the argument in the OP.
